# GCM in Delphi Seattle without BAAS

Tags: delphi, google-cloud-messaging, delphi-10-seattle

I am trying to implement GCM without BAAS in GCM. I have looked at previous examples using the bridge and from my research the following should work without relying on the old TGCMReceiver component.

But the following line always returns nil, I run this after the application starts up on a button click:

```
APushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.GCM);
```

APushService is always nil.

My AndroidManifest looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.embarcadero.Project1"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0"
        android:installLocation="auto">

    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <permission android:name="com.embarcadero.Project1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.embarcadero.Project1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="Project1" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4323000" />


        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="Project1"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="Project1" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

<receiver
      android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMNotification" android:exported="true"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="com.embarcadero.Project1" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMNotification" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<category android:name="com.embarcadero.Project1" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

I have tried using the common TGCMReceiver application that is out there from CodeRage9 using XE8, it doesn't work in XE10 / Seattle and it does appear that XE10 is updated in this regard but I cannot make anything work with simple Google Cloud Messaging and am looking for some guidance.

Comment: Ive also tried what was indicated in here for XE 6. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205478/issue-with-gcm-push-notification-service-delphi-xe6/27690786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is shown here: [Issue with GCM Push notification service DELPHI XE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205478/issue-with-gcm-push-notification-service-delphi-xe6/27690786)

Except with .Active := True not AutoActivate := True as indicated by the Answer.

TL;DR version. Drop TKinvyProvider on form with just the GCMAppID populated, Drop TPushEvent on Form with AutoRegister and AutoActivate set to false. In entitlement list set "support push notification : true".. add in the following to your AndroidManifest.template.xml:

```
<service android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMIntentService" />
```

Right before `</application>`.